# deploy index.php in iis

Tags: php, iis, deployment

I made a small application that displays a tree of directories and their files, photos and videos. It is a single php file. I need to display that index.php file in an iis but I don't know how. I have tried to make an iis web site point to the folder where I have the php file and nothing opens.

- try deploy index.php in iis.
- expected shoy the web site.
- not open index.php.

Comment: Did you install PHP in IIS? Did you create a website in IIS which points to that folder where the file is? What URL did you then use in your browser to open it? What happened when you accessed that URL (I highly doubt it literally did _nothing_). We don't know any of this, we cannot see your machine and you didn't explain the situation in sufficient detail. You can [edit] your question if you need more help. See also [ask]. Thanks.

Comment: the iis has php, when I open the url I get an error message, I do not remember what it was, when I have it I will share it. I just wanted to know if you have to configure something special for a single index.php file to be deployed in an iis and it works.

Comment: when I run it locally with xampp it works perfectly but when I upload it to the iis it does not work when I open the url

Comment: The error message is pretty much essential for answering this question, without it we're just guessing at things.

Comment: `I just wanted to know if you have to configure something special for a single index.php file to be deployed in an iis`...other than what I mentioned above, no. The error message is key to this, I'm not really sure why you didn't mention it before. Details are always important in programming.

Comment: `index.php` is not in the default document list, so you need to add it explicitly, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/defaultdocument/ Besides, run a report to rule out common issues https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/php-diagnostics.html

Comment: Does it work when you add `php.index` to the default documentation module of your IIS website?

Comment: I added index.php as default file as you said and the error disappeared. Now the problem is that my index does not show anything, just an empty html, it is strange because locally with xampp it works perfect. The iis I think it does not have the php module installed apparently, but there are already applications with php running on that server and I do not know how that can happen.  In C: there is a php installation, I do not know if somehow these projects are using that php installation outside the iis, I am new to server issues and there are many things I do not know. Thank you very much.

Comment: If you get a blank page, ensure you've got php error reporting enabled. Check the page source to see what output you actually got. Check the browser's network tool to see what the http response code was. You need to learn more techniques for doing basic investigation into what is happening. That then gives you more clues about what the root of the problem might be

Comment: What is php.index? is that same thing of index.php?

Comment: i dont know, a guy edit de post and he changed index.php to php.index... is fixed jet

Comment: the iis has php installed but by cgi as shown in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p-Yc4L3NPg8. I have tried with a simple echo hellow world and it works, so the error must be inside the code, something that is not compatible with the php of the iis, because in local with xampp it works without any problem. I will try to find how to enable php error reporting as ADyson says.

Comment: I enabled display_errors as @ADyson said and I could see the errors in the code. The problem was a Parser Exception because of the PHP version, using isset to check if variables are Null fixed it. I have another problem but I will open it in another post since the problem mentioned here has already been solved, thank you very much to all.

Comment: Hi Earendil, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! If you don't mind, please consider writing this solution as an answer and accept it. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Comment: Hi YurongDai, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I enabled display_errors as @ADyson said and I could see the errors in the code. The problem was a Parser Exception because of the PHP version, using isset to check if variables are Null fixed it.